# Como alterar labels de um formulario em módulos diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, pyqt-5

Estou usando Python 3.7

Tenho 2 formulários (janelas) que fiz com PyQT5, em um deles tem algumas labels que preciso alterar de acordo com a configuração da janela de configurações.

criei um módulos com a seguinte função:

```
def calculaTaxas(self):
    valorBase = self.ui.lbl_saldoAtual.text()
```

Quando chamo a função pela janela principal, os dados carregam normalmente.

Mas quando altero os dados e tento chamar a função pela janela de configurações para atualizar a tela principal com os valores novos, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_frm_Config' object has no attribute 'lbl_saldoAtual'
```

Entendi que ele ta passando o form de config para o self da função, tentei de diversas formas atualizar a tela e não consegui, nem mesmo tentando chamar diretamente:

```
valorBase = Ui_frm_principal.lbl_saldoAtual.text()
```

Oq eu gostaria mesmo era de poder chamar a função calculaTaxas() sem o SELF como parametro para eu poder atualizar a tela principal de qualquer parte do código ou janela.

Não sei se é relevante, mas segue a configuração das telas.

Tela Principal:

```
class TelaPrincipal(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self,*args,**argsv):        
        super(TelaPrincipal,self).__init__(*args,**argsv)
        self.ui = Ui_frm_principal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Tela de configuração:

```
class TelaConfig(QMainWindow):     
    def __init__(self,*args,**argsv):
        super(TelaConfig,self).__init__(*args,**argsv)
        self.ui = Ui_frm_Config()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, eu utilizo um controlador para chamar funções e variaveis da tela principal, talvez isto te ajude:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class TelaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TelaPrincipal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.ui = Ui_frm_principal()
        # self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tela Principal')
        self.setGeometry(100, 200, 300, 200)

        self.tela_config = TelaConfig(self)

        self.saldo_actual = QLabel(self)
        self.saldo_actual.move(100, 100)

    def calculaTaxas(self):
        valorBase = self.tela_config.saldo.value()
        self.saldo_actual.setText(str(valorBase))


class TelaConfig(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        # self.ui = Ui_frm_Config()
        # self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.controller = controller

        self.setWindowTitle('Tela Config')
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 300, 200)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.saldo = QSpinBox(self)
        self.saldo.move(100, 100)
        self.saldo.valueChanged.connect(self.controller.calculaTaxas)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.saldo)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = TelaPrincipal()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```